# Замена всех вхождений

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно заменить все вхождения `[br]` в заголовках `h1` на тег `</br>`. Пишу следующий код:

```
jQuery('h1').each(function() {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    text.replace(/\[br]/g, '</br>');
    jQuery(this).text(text);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjq263ex/

Работать не хочет, хотя регулярное выражение, вроде, правильное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде есть ряд проблем:

1. Вы не правильно осуществляете замену. Метод [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) возвращает обновленную строку, а не проводит замены в текущей.
2. Метод [`jQuery.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) экранирует все теги из переданной строки, заменяя управляющие символы HTML-сущностями. Вам нужно использовать метод [`jQuery.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
3. Тег `br` имеет вид `<br />` а не `</br>` (обратите внимание на положение слеша). Ваш вариант не соответствует стандартам, хотя и должен работать в браузерах.

Таким образом, правильный код имеет вид:

```
jQuery('h1').each(function() {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    text = text.replace(/\[br]/g, '<br />');
    jQuery(this).html(text);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9e7u8xv/1/) с работающим примером.

Comment: вообще говоря я проверил с текущим выражением - тоже работает.

Comment: @Grundy, как бы то ни было, управляющие символы лучше эскейпировать. Ну и это не единственная проблема в коде ТС

Comment: Метод .text() ничего не вырезает он экранирует символы кода HTML.

Comment: @walik, вы правы, обновил ответ

Comment: Символ `]` нужно экранировать только в символьном классе. Здесь не нужно этого делать. Экранировать надо только то, что необходимо экранировать.

Answer (score 3):

[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) возвращает новую строку, не меняя текущую.

> Этот метод не изменяет объект String, на котором он вызывается. Он просто возвращает новую строку.

нужно

```
jQuery(this).text(text.replace(/\[br\]/g, '</br>'));
```

как заметил @walik, если нужно вставить *html* вместо функции [*text*](http://api.jquery.com/text/) нужно использовать [*html*](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
jQuery(this).html(text.replace(/\[br\]/g, '</br>'))
```

Comment: И самое важное забыли, метод .text() выведет html "как он есть", нужно использовать .html() для того что бы все сработало.

Comment: @walik, добавил замечание :-)